# Windows 7 Backup and Restore. How does it work

Tags: backup, restore

I want to backup, re-install and then restore my files. However I want to be sure that if after re-installing windows **all my files as they were would be back**. Is that what happens?

Also I don't have an external drive to put the back up in it, but I have another laptop, how can I save the backup on the other laptop? Or should I create a hard disk partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, backing up and then restoring works, if that is what you are asking.

In order to save the backup on another laptop, you would need to map the other laptop as a network drive.

A hard disk partition would work if your OS dies, but not if your hard drive dies.

Comment: Thanks for your response, what I need is for windows to have a frsh installation, fresh settings but with my files intact, is that possible. I dont want to restore the OLD and broken Windows files.

Comment: So just select the option to just backup your data, not the system.

Answer (score 0):

Below are steps to be taken care:-

1. To re-installing, first you require Windows 7 OS CD.
2. Before you start, take a Backup of your files
3. Connect another laptop through the network cable
4. If your laptop is **DELL** then you have built-in software "DELL DataSafe" for taking backup and restore
5. Using the software, go for option full system backup / only required files
6. While taking backup, make sure two laptops having power supply until the process is completed.
7. New partition is not required on the another laptop

If you buy Western Digital (WD) external hard disk, it also help you to take backup and restore on the laptop.